# IFNULL() Equivalent in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, ifnull, nullif

I am working on a project of migrating from MySQL to PostgreSQL, some function can't works well in PostgreSQL like `IFNULL` function. Some tutorials say that in PostgreSQL we can use `NULLIF` to handle it. 
When I try I get an issue "`argument of NOT must be type boolean, not type integer`".

This is the simple SQL :

```
SELECT * FROM `tableA` WHERE not(nullif(columnA, 0));
```

How to solve it? Maybe some one can make an explain how can it works well. Thanks

Comment: nullif returns null WHEN your two parameters are EQUAL, otherwise, it will return the FIRST parameter given. Your "not(nullif(columnA, 0))" will be evaluated to be either "not(null)" or "not(columnA)", which hardly is what you meant.

Comment: Thanks @Stacking For Heap, I can understand how it works finally.

Comment: Great, please accept my answer

Answer (score 10):

NULLIF() is very different from IFNULL().  I think that what you want is COALESCE(), which will return the first non-NULL argument (it can have more than 2 arguments):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table_a
WHERE  NOT (COALESCE(column_a::boolean, false));
```

Reference: [9.17.2. COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)

Also, in Postgres you need to use `true` or `false`.  0 and 1 do not work for boolean literals.  That's the reason that you get the error:

> argument of NOT must be type boolean, not type integer

If `column_a` is an integer, then you have to CAST it to `boolean`.  That's what `column_a::boolean` in the example above does.  It is equivalent to `CAST(column_a AS boolean)`.

Comment: @laurenz-albe That's exactly what I wrote if you re-read my answer, and the OP.  The OP is looking for a function comparable to `IFNULL()`

Comment: Thanks @isapir, Your answer is what I need. When I try as what you say, I can see the different, especially about duration when script was being execute.